# Email is not receiving in recipient's email box while using sendgrid in protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor, sendgrid, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber framework.I am tryig to implement sendgrid method for email sending.For that i have used api from https://sendgrid.com/free/. I am using sendgrid/mail version 5.2.3 and used below code.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
var env=require('../support/sendgrid.js');
sgMail.setApiKey(env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
console.log(env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'xx@gmail.com',
  from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

I am exporting the api from sendgrid.js(i am able to successfully launch the api to the code).When i ran the above code initially, the email not received, then i directly hardcoded the api in the code, then it worked.So i again try to export it from the sendgrid.js file.That time also it worked.But after running the code 2,3 times then again the email was not receiving in the recipient list.I am not understanding why this behave inconsistently.Also i am not able to console whether there is a success or failure.How can we catch/print the error here.Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: I think here issue in `sengrid` instead of protractor

Comment: So where i am going wrong in above code?Can anyone guide me..